# SharedEventManger and __NAMESPACE__

Tags: zend-framework2, zfcuser

I'm attempting to check for user login for every route as detailed in this ZfcUser issue: https://github.com/ZF-Commons/ZfcUser/issues/187

Attach an event to the MvcEvent::EVENT_ROUTE event - simple.

However, I only want to protect my Admin module not the Application one. I'm sure I used to be able to use the SharedEventManger to attached the event to a specific namespace but this doesn't seem to be working any more - has the SharedEventManger altered in recent ZF2 versions?

My code:

```
namespace Admin;

use Zend\ModuleManager\ModuleManager;
use Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent;

class Module
{

    public function init(ModuleManager $moduleManager) {
        $sharedEventManager = $moduleManager->getEventManager()->getSharedManager();
        $sharedEventManager->attach(
            __NAMESPACE__,
            MvcEvent::EVENT_ROUTE,
            array('Admin\Authentication\Enforcer', 'enforceApplication'), 
            -100
        );
    }

    ...
```

If I alter the first attribute from _ _ NAMESPACE _ _ to '*' the event is fired!

How to I attached a 'route' event so it is only fired within a specific namespace?
Or Once the event has been fired how to I get the namespace of the trigger so I can add an 'if Admin' clause.

Many thanks in advance.

Pete

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to identify the Admin module from the route:

```
    /**
     * Is this an Admin event (determined by route)
     * 
     * @param \Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent $e
     * @return boolean
     */
    static public function isAdmin(MvcEvent $e) {
        $match = $e->getRouteMatch();
        $controller = $e->getTarget();
        if (
            !$match instanceof \Zend\Mvc\Router\RouteMatch || 
            0 !== strpos($match->getMatchedRouteName(), 'admin') || 
            (
                $controller instanceof \Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractController &&
                $controller->getEvent()->getResult()->terminate()
            )
        ) {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
```

Is there a better way than this? Ideally using the SharedEventManger's first parameter.

Thanks,
Pete